# JS rule to affect 2 separate links on hover

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I've spent the past several hours trying to work out a hover effect for 2 separate links on a site I'm working on.   The links aren't even remotely related in the HTML, so I'm unable to use CSS (as far as I can see) to achieve the effect.  It's nothing more than a simple hover effect to change the color of two separate links on hove, regardless of which one the user hovers over.  There are no images at this point, only text - I'm hoping it stays that way (I'm looking at you, graphic designer wife).

The html involves a bootstrap navbar & a link on the home page of a WordPress site, so the architecture is something like this:

```
                <div class="collapse navbar-collapse">
                    <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                        <li><a class="abt" href="#">About</a></li>
                        <li><a class="prc" href="#">Work</a></li>
                        <li><a class="exp" href="#">Testimonials</a></li>
                        <li><a class="ofc" href="#">Locations</a></li>
                        <li><a class="con" href="#">Contact</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>


    <section id="content" role="main">
    <article id="post-10" class="post-10 page type-page status-publish hentry">
    <header class="header">
    <h1 class="entry-title">Home</h1> <a class="post-edit-link" href="#post.php?post=10&amp;action=edit">Edit This</a></header>
    <section class="entry-content">
    <div class="links">
    <li><a class="abt" href="#/about/"><span class="pg abt1">
    <p>About</p>
    <p></span></a></li>
```

I'd like to focus on the "About" sections for this - I'm pretty sure that I need either jQuery or JS to accomplish what I'm after but I'm a rank beginner in both!

Comment: please update question to give this info, seems to be lacking. " when I hhover on _______ then I expect ________ to happen.' thanks!  not sure wht you're asking

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alright, so you're right. You need jQuery. First of all, what you should do is give the two link tags the same class, let's say foo. Give both link tags the class foo. Then, use jQuery to target them both.

Now, id you want it to change the color permanently on hover, use THIS:

```
$('.foo').hover(function(){
$('.foo').css('color', 'red');
});
```

Feel free to change red to whatever color you like. Now, if you want the color to change only while being hovered over, use this:

```
$('.foo').mouseenter(function(){
$('.foo').css('color', 'red');
});

$('.foo').mouseleave(function(){
$('.foo').css('color', 'black');
});
```

in the second chunk, change black to whatever the original color is. If you are unfamiliar with how to use JQuery, add the following tag into your code below the CSS stylesheet (if applicable)

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

This makes the browser read the jQuery. If you don't have this, the browser can't read the jQuery.

Then, copy and paste either one of the two bits of jQuery into a file, save it as a .js file, and then attach it via `<script>` tag after the tag listed above. Alternatively, put the jQuery between two script tags as such:

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
//one of the two blocks of JQuery here
</script>
```

Put that in your code After the tag that allows you to use jQuery.

EDIT: I received a request for code to make them different colors. The code would look like this:

First of all, you can keep or remove the class. Then assign them separate IDs , say id_1 and id_2. Then, using the first method:

```
$('#id_1').hover(function(){
$(this).css('color', 'red');
});
$('#id_2').hover(function(){
$(this).css('color', 'red');
});
```

This would change the color permanent when hovered on. Using the second method to change the color while being hovered on:

```
$('#id_1').mouseenter(function(){
$(this).css('color', 'red');
});
$('#id_1').mouseleave(function(){
$(this).css('color', 'black');
});
```

then do the same thing, but switch id_1 for id_2 and change the colors to whatever. The first color is the color being changed to, and the second one the color being set back to the original.

Comment: That's brilliant! At the risk of pushing my luck, what if I want one of the two elements in the given class to be a different color than the other?

Comment: That would be possible. I'll update my answer for you. gimme five minutes.

Comment: Awesome! That's much simpler than I was thinking last night. I think I hear more education calling my name ..

Comment: check out http://www.codecademy.com/  i used it to learn most of what I know of coding. I love their HTML+CSS tutorial, JQuery, and Ruby tutorials. Check it out

Comment: You bet - I've had pretty good luck so far with Udemy, too.  Thanks again!